# Adding the running sense on a line integral on a closed path

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

I want to type the integral symbol over a closed path by specifying its (let's say counterclockwise) orientation, through an arrow.

How can I add an arrow on the middle circle over the integral sign:

```
\oint\limits_{Gamma}x\,\mathrm{d}\gamma
```

[image]

?

Comment: `\ointctrclockwise` from `txfonts` or `\esint` packages, for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two examples with `txfonts` and `esint`, both provide the `\ointctrclockwise` macro, but look different. There is `\ointclockwise` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

$\ointctrclockwise\limits_{\Gamma} x \mathrm{d}\gamma$

\end{document}
```

[image]

`esint` version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}

\[\ointctrclockwise\limits_{\Gamma} x \mathrm{d}\gamma\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Cris: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!